# Access any software through excel or Scripting or Task?

Tags: windows, excel, scheduled-tasks, vba

I am using software which actually send a message to LED message display but It needs to press send button every time.Is there anyway to access that button or make any task which actually press that button after some seconds.Because I want to send the message continuously after 2 seconds.

Comment: Tip: you can use 'Application.OnTime'

Comment: Could you please post a screenshot showing that LED message board application? Also please let me know whether it is always on top over other windows.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is not a full answer to your question, I do not have sufficient reputation to add a comment.

If the LED message display software that you are using does not have a published interface to allow you to control it then you may need to use API calls. You can declare a function which makes a call directly to the API library. A useful call is FindWindowExA. This finds information about the windows open on the computer. All the windows are in a hierarchy. You can then find the application window for the LED message software and step through the sub windows until you find the one that represents the send button. You should be able to active its press event.

API calls are declared like this:
Private Declare Function local_name Lib "user32" Alias "library_routine_name" (....) As long

where local_name is the name of the function in your code and library_routine_name is the name of the routine that you wish to call

for example:
`Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, _
ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long`

declares a function called FindWindowEx which calls the library routine FindWindowExA. The arguments to the call are specified by the routine that you are calling.

MSDN provides descriptions of the API calls, for example see
[FindWindow help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[FindWindowExA help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)